# Using $http() to send a Put request passing header and body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, put

I want to send a request to a server and get a response :

```
app.factory('statistics', function($http) {

var getData = function(...) {
    // Angular $http() and then() both return promises themselves

    var data = {
      ...
    };

    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
    alert(dataString);
    return $http({
      method: "PUT",
      url: getStatistics,
      headers: {
        'loginId': ...,
        'token': ...,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: { data: dataString, }

    }).then(function(result){
      var dataString = JSON.stringify(result.data);

        return result.data;
    });
};

return { getData: getData };
});
```

The problem is that I am getting repeatedly Error 400 (bad request).
I tried to use POSTMAN and the request worked on it :

the 3 paramethers login,token and content was added in the postman header, and the data object has been added in the postman's body section.

How can I solve this Issue ?

Comment: Can you verify from the network that the data being sent along with request is valid ?

Comment: I can't... but if i do it with the same value on postman... it works

Comment: check if there should be a comma after `data: dataString`, also try this method of sending your data: `$http.put(url, data, config).then(...)`

Comment: it doesn't work ;(

Comment: Try changing `data: {...}` to `params: {...}`, otherwise you might have a problem in your **backend**, check how you handle the request in PHP or whatever you use